# Where does Narada muni lives

Tags: rishi, narada

[This thread](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14796/16263) explains different lokas in detail.

In which of these lokas, Narada Muni lives? Is there a reference in puranas about this?

Answer (score -1):

Narada Muni does not live at any specific place. Because of curse of Daksha Prajapati, he keep roaming in all three lokas.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is that curse? Is it mentioned in any scripture about that? Which are those 3 lokas?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE, answers here should be backed up authentic sources. Please cite sources. Visit help section to know more.